# Unable to delete localStorage on button click

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button which should delete item from local storage on click event, but it's not working.

html:

```
 <form class="delet" onsubmit="reset(); return false">
        <button>Löschen</button>
    </form>
```

js:

```
function reset() {
    localStorage.removeItem("monday");
}
```

Comment: [Don't use `on...` attributes for event handling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Event_handlers#registering_event_handlers), instead add an event listener for the `sumbit` event on your form element on the JS side, so that your HTML stays "just HTML'. Having said that, "it isn't working" isn't a problem description so what proof do you have, and what [mcve] can you form to show that? E.g. as HTML/JS problem you should be able to turn this problem case into a runnable code snippet in your post, so hit the [edit] button and [update your post with that](/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: the function at it own is workin if I type reset(); in the console but if I press the button the function isn't called up

Comment: So show that off: edit your post to a full, working example, using the runnable snippet code embed option in the button bar of the editor view.

Comment: If you change the name of the function to resetStorage, does it start working?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans problem with that is the sandbox does not support localStorage

Comment: That is indeed a problem. In which case jsbin or repl.it or the like is probably a good idea, because a [mcve] is still missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem you have is form has a [reset method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset) and that is what is being triggered. You can see that when you add a text field. Add some text and submit and you see the text removed.

```html
<form class="delet" onsubmit="reset(); return false">
  <input type="text">
  <button>Löschen</button>
</form>
```

Solution, rename your function

```js
function resetStorage(){
  console.log('called');
}
```

```html
<form class="delet" onsubmit="resetStorage(); return false">
  <button>Löschen</button>
</form>
```